# Change a function returning multiple unidimension arrays into one returning one unidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a function which I want to retrieve key/value pairs from db, and it comes like `$result=array($key=>$value);` and when I use this `$result`, in an object requiring an array in its parameters

```
function Foo($result) { array ('superkey'=>$result); }
```

this considers that $result contains multiple arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
)
Array
(
    [key3] => value2
)
Array
(
    [key3] => value3
)
Array
(
    [key4] => value4
)
```

But I want it to consider it as one array:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1

    [key3] => value2

    [key3] => value3

    [key4] => value4
)
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: you can't have multiple array elements with the same key value

Comment: Could you provide the exact data you getting from db?

Comment: Am makin a Symfony framework project, and my select tag with elements of database:
            $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add(
                'sectoption',
                'choice',
                array(
                    'choices' =>
                    $result,
                    
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Select a section'
                    )
            )
                ->getForm();
            $createview = $form->createView();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve values from a database, it usually sends a multi-dimensional array like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> array(1) { ["samekey"]=> value1 }
  [1]=> array(1) { ["samekey"]=> value2 }
  [2]=> array(1) { ["samekey"]=> value3 }
}
```

The keys of these arrays are always the same, because they represent the column name from the database. It sounds to me like you're looking for a way to compile all those values into a single array. To do that, you need to forget about the key, and use something ike this:

```
foreach($result as $entry) $fixedresult[] = $entry['samekey'];
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `array_map(function($entry) { return $entry['samekey'];}, $result)`

Comment: What do you mean here by 'samekey' I wish u use keyword I used in question, and I'd ask will this return the what I was expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, ...);
```

Comment: I am not accessing these array, I have them at the return of the function but I have just inserted the $result=array($key=>$value), because I am supposed to don't know which result to get from the database!
So I can't use array_merge because I don't have yet these arrays at the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use `array_merge` on a number of arrays, but you don't know yet how many it will be, you can do the following:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);
```

Although this will break as soon as the arrays contained in `$result` have the same key, as others have pointed out.